# Jsonata filter value by looking at parent element

Tags: json, jsonata

I've a JSON blob in the following form:

```
{
  "allEntries": [
     {
        "property": {
           "type": "ab"
        }, "values": {
           "score": 10.40
        }
     },
     {
        "property": {
           "type": "ty"
        }, "values": {
           "score": 90.45
        }
     }

  ]
}
```

I want to just check if the score of property type `ab` is less than 10. However `$min(allEntries.values.score)` goes through all the properties and does not filter out types which I'm not interested in. 
I tried using the parent property '%.' however that doesn't work either (`The object representing the 'parent' cannot be derived from this expression`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what the desired output is, but you can filter the list of array entries using the following expression:

```
allEntries[property.type='ab' and values.score < 10]
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/BzJKGrIIG

Comment: How about in https://try.jsonata.org/dhgsUm7kr I want to return true if min score is less than 5 for `Reference type=random or  Reference type=randomAc. I want to ignore Reference Type=randomAb`

Comment: You can use a regex to match the property name and sift the properties based on that:

```
$sift(fields, function($v, $k) {
    $k ~> /Reference\(map={type=random(Ac)?}\)/ and $number($v.labels.score) < 5
})
```
https://try.jsonata.org/v8irnAzpq